# Are there any objections to using the same (unlabelled) data for pre-training of a BERT-Based model and the downstream task?

Tags: nlp, bert, pretraining

I'm looking to train an Electra model using unlabelled data in a specific field. Are there any objections to using the same data for unsupervised learning and then using the same data downstream for the supervised learning task?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. A recent [ACL paper by AllenAI](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.acl-main.740.pdf) even says this is the best way. They recommend continuing pre-training on the task data and claim that it reduces the problems caused by domain mismatch. So, if you train the model on the in-domain data from the very beginning, it is probably a good thing given you have enough data for that.